# Filter and collect a Map<String, List<Object>> to Map<String, List<Object>> based on a condition

Tags: java

Let

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

My variable is

```
Map<Sring, List<Person>> myVariable;
```

The result I'm aiming to get is

```
Map<String, List<Person>> result;
```

The condition is to collect all persons satisfying this condition

```
Predicate<Person> predicate = p -> p.age > 20;
```

If an entry in the map contains 3 persons and only 2 of them satisfies this condition, the 3rd one should be removed

Example: myVariable =

```
"1": [{name: "Foo", age: 15}, {name: "Foo", age: 13}, {name: "Foo", age: 14}]
"2": [{name: "Foo", age: 15}, {name: "Foo", age: 13}, {name: "Foo", age: 14}]
"3": [{name: "Foo", age: 15}, {name: "Foo", age: 13}, {name: "Foo", age: 14}]
"4": [{name: "Foo", age: 15}, {name: "Foo", age: 21}, {name: "Foo", age: 27}]
```

result =

```
"4": {name: "Foo", age: 21}, {name: "Foo", age: 27}]
```

I tried this

```
Map<String, List<Persin>> result = myVariable.keySet().stream()
            .filter(p -> myVariable.keySet(p).stream().anyMatch(predicate))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p, myVariable.get(Function.identity()).stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two `filter` calls:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> result = myVariable.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> Map.entry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()
                .stream().filter(p -> p.getAge() > 20)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
        .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

If you're on Java 8, replace `Map.entry()` with `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry()`.

Comment: I used SimpleEntry and I got Unchecked call to 'SimpleEntry(K, V)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry'

Comment: @Pryda You should use `new SimpleEntry<>(k, v)`. It's a generic class.

Comment: I was coming to the same code when I saw this answer. Try it: https://www.jdoodle.com/a/3r0I

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @ernest_k's correct answer using the predicate provided and pre filtering the entryset to not care about empty lists:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Example {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<Person> predicate = p -> p.age > 20;
        Map<String, List<Person>> myVariable = // your map

        Map<String, List<Person>> result =
        myVariable.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().anyMatch(predicate))
                .map(entry -> {
                    List<Person> temp = entry.getValue().stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    return new SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), temp);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```